# UPDATE record DB from form PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a page "elenco.php" where i show all DB record in a table and in each row at the end i have a button "edit"  that submit to the page "edit.php" the "ID" of the row that the user would like to edit .

**elenco.php**

```
  <?php 
    include '/var/www/phpMyEdit/open_dati.php';


    $query = "SELECT * FROM scadenziario"; 
    $result= mysql_query($query);


    echo "<h2>Elenco Scadenziario</h2>";

        echo "<table border>";
            echo "<tr><td>ID</td><td>Aspetto Generale</td><td>Descrizione</td><td>Ragione Sociale</td><td>Numero Civico</td><td>Validita</td><td>Data</td><td>Preavviso</td><td>Scadenza</td><td>Prescrizioni</td><td>Frequenza</td><td>Data Controllo</td><td>Prossimo Controllo</td><td>Note</td>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $row[ID] . 
                    "</td><td>". $row[Aspetto_Generale]. 
                    "</td><td>". $row[Descrizione].
                    "</td><td>". $row[Ragione_Sociale].
                    "</td><td>". $row[Num_Civico].
                    "</td><td>". $row[Validita].
                    "</td><td>". $row[Data].
                    "</td><td>". $row[Preavviso].
                    "</td><td>". $row[Scadenza].
                    "</td><td>". $row[Prescrizioni].
                    "</td><td>". $row[Frequenza].
                    "</td><td>". $row[Data_Controllo].
                    "</td><td>". $row[Prox_Controllo].
                    "</td><td>". $row[Note].
                    "</td><td><form action='edit.php' method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='tempID' value='".$row['ID']."'/><input type='submit' name='submit-btn' value='Edit' /><form></td></tr>";
                }
        echo "</table>";

    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

**edit.php**

```
 <?echo'
        <html>
        <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
        </head>';

        include '/var/www/phpMyEdit/open_dati.php';

        $temp = $_POST['tempID'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM scadenziario WHERE ID = '$temp' "; 
        $result= mysql_query($query);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    $aspettogen = $row['Aspetto_Generale'];
                    $desc = $row['Descrizione'];
                    $ragsoc = $row['Ragione_Sociale'];
                    $numcivico = $row['Num_Civico'];
                    $validita = $row['Valdita'];
                    $odierna = $row['Data'];
                    $preavviso = $row['Preavviso'];
                    $scadenza = $row['Scadenza'];
                    $presc = $row['Prescrizioni'];
                    $freq = $row['Frequenza'];
                    $datacontr = $row['Data_Controllo'];
                    $proxcontr = $row['Prox_Controllo'];
                    $note = $row['Note'];
            }?>



    <? echo'
        <body>
            <div class="container">  
                <form id="contact" method="POST">'?>



                <? echo'
                                <img src="logo.jpg"> 
                                <fieldset>
                                <input name="aspettogen2" type="text" value="'.$aspettogen.'">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input name="desc" type="text" maxlength="255" value="'.$desc.'">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input name="ragsoc" type="text" maxlength="100">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input name="numcivico"  type="text" maxlength="20">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input name="validita" type="text">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input name="odierna" type="data">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input name="preavviso" type="text">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input name="scadenza" type="text">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input name="presc" type="text" maxlength="255">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input name="freq" type="number">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input name="datacontr" type="text">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input name="proxcontr" type="text">
                                </fieldset>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <input name="note" type="text">
                                </fieldset>             
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>';

    mysql_close(); 
    ?>
```

but i cant understand why in the page edit.php the id value is always the last record of the table DB.

for example my table has 35 record, if i click the edit button of the row 10 in the page "elenco.php", in the page edit.php i receive always ID = 35 ( the last record of the DB).

Can u help me guys?

Comment: Did you check the source code?

Comment: Do you see 35 on all hidden inputs on your browser console?

Comment: in the console of the page i see the correct value on each button edit, but in the page edit.php i receive always the last record

Comment: `echo "<tr><td>ID</td><td> //table;` missing closing quotes there

Comment: there are few quote (`'` and `"`) mistakes in elenco.php file. Correct it and check again.

Comment: in the original code there are the qoutes

Comment: i've pasted the original codes "elenco.php"

Comment: Use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` since `mysql`  is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.x. Read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Comment: Close the `form` tag under while loop and make sure that every element of `$row` must enclosed within quotes in "elenco.php"

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: the problem is in your form. If you want to do like this you need to have each form with a different name and check which form is posted. You have 35 forms that overwrites with each other

Comment: the ID value should be correct even if my forms is wrong, but in var_dump i receive 35 as value ID array(2) { ["tempID"]=> string(2) "35" ["submit-btn"]=> string(4) "Edit" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your mysql* functions for mysqli* functions in elenco.php and edit.php.

then check everything inside the post array, and make sure you're getting all the data with

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

and this code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM scadenziario WHERE ID = '$temp' ";
```

i assume your id is an integer type, so you don't have to use ' ', try:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM scadenziario WHERE ID = $temp ";
```

hope this can help.

Comment: array(2) { ["tempID"]=> string(2) "35" ["submit-btn"]=> string(4) "Edit" }

i receive 35 i dont understand why

Comment: ok, did you try replacing the mysql with mysqli functions? mysql is deprecated, so it might give you some problems (you need to pass the connection link as the first param of the mysqli_query($connection, $query))

Comment: i just noticed something, in your elenco.php, in the form with the id value, you're not closing the form, you have <form><form>, and should be </form>